# WebdriverIO loop through element list using Java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have a grid with a dynamic number of rows and I want to get the content for each row. below is a sample and I want to be able to get the "This can’t be a single letter." and "Enter the last name of the contact person."

I tried

```
var text = $('#topErrorList');

console.log(text.$$('li')[0].$('a').getText()); 
// And
console.log(text.$$('li')[0].getText('a'));
```

both didn't work

Failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined

```
 <div id="topErrors">
<h3 id="topErrorTitle">Your information contains 2 error(s).</h3>
<ul id="topErrorList">
    <li>
        <a href="" tabindex="0">This can’t be a single letter.</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" tabindex="0">Enter the last name of the contact person.</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok we have the info of what you want, now what did you tried? What's the error you are getting from the code you've tried?

Comment: I tried 

 var text = $('#topErrorList');
console.log(text.$$('li')[0].getText('a'));

Failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried and the results.

Comment: I just did Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve it using `jquery` selector and `.each()` method.

```js
// Get the title
const contentTitle = $('#topErrorTitle').html().trim();

console.log(contentTitle);


// Get the N Rows texts
const rowContents = [];

// Look at each <a>
$('#topErrorList li a').each(function(elem) {
  // Get the content and push it into the array
  rowContents.push($(this).html().trim());
});

// Display the array
console.log(rowContents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="topErrors">
  <h3 id="topErrorTitle">Your information contains 2 error(s).</h3>

  <ul id="topErrorList">
    <li>
      <a href="" tabindex="0">This can’t be a single letter.</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" tabindex="0">Enter the last name of the contact person.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```